# Trocar POST padrao do form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho um funcao Jquery que cria um objeto JSON exatamente como eu preciso. Ao final dessa funcao eu envio um POST para uma API passando esse objeto

`$.post('http://localhost:3000/testStatus', objeto)`

Eu chamo a funcao que cria esse objeto num butao dentro do form, algo como:

```
<form method="post" action="/testStatus">
   <!-- Resto do html, contento inputs e tudo mais... -->
    <button onclick="postData()">INICIAR</button>
</form>
```

Acontece que a funcao manda o POST como eu quero e form tambem manda outro POST, ou seja, em um click o formulario manda 2 POST seguidos. Eu nao posso substituir o `method="POST"` pelo GET ou remove-lo. Eu preciso enviar apenas o POST da minha funcao `postData()`

Uma alternativa para isso, seria eu trocar de pagina ( ir para testStatus ) atraves do meu post em jquery, dessa forma eu nao precisaria colocar o button dentro do form. Mas nao sei fazer isso com jquery

Comment: Coloque `$("form").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });` no script para impedir que o form seja submetido.

Comment: Isso funciona em parte, mas eu ainda preciso carregar a pagina testStatus. E ela so eh carregada atraves de um post

Comment: Então porque não faz o post pelo action em vez do jQuery. Não estou conseguindo entender direito o que vc quer fazer :/

Comment: Acontece que eu estou gerando diversos inputs automaticamente atraves do Handlebars, e  acaba que ele esta gerando esses inputs sem o `name`, entao eu nao consigo capturar eles. Mais cedo tentei fazer uma funcao usando jquery para colocar o atributo de name nesses inputs, mas acabou que nao deu mt certo.. entao optei por essa solucao, mas tbm nao esta como eu queria..

Comment: A página testStatus  só carrega via post? Vc quer fazer o Ajax e depois carregar a página?

Comment: Sim, ela so carrega via POST. No caso, seria antes.. Eu fiz uma funcao que quando clica no botao, ela cria um objeto que seria passado para a pagina `testStatus` e ela deveria carregar a pagina junto com esse objeto

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97077/discussion-between-sam-and-matheus-barbosa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque um input hidden no formulário e envie o objeto para ele antes do submit normal via post do action, e não via Ajax. Assim você consegue receber esse input no backend e tratar o objeto como quiser.

Seria algo assim:

```
<form...>
   ....
   <input type="hidden" name="objeto">
   <button>INICIAR</button>
</form>

<script>
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // cancela o submit automático
   var $this = $(this);

   // código que cria o objeto

   // insere o objeto no campo
   $("[name=objeto]").val(objeto);

   // delay para inserir dados no input antes do submit
   setTimeout(function(){
      $this.submit(); // envia o form
   }, 100);
});
</script>
```